# How to fix "Exception: Invalid channel" error in my API

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to save a object Using HTTP Post Method in my API Controller, but it's returning a error, i've tried to do the same in another controler and it works. I hope you may help!

The Request that I tried:

```
  {
    "integrationServiceHost": "10.80.80.10",
    "RouterHost": "10.80.80.10",
    "Enabled": "false",
    "IntegrationServiceRemotePort": "1234",
    "RouterSocketPort":"1234",
    "RouterRemotePort":"1234",
    "IDChannelBehavior":"10",
    "IDEPS":"1",
    "Description":"Teste Whats",
    "IDChannel":"0"
  }
```

ChannelWhatsapp Class:

```
public class ChannelWhatsApp : Channel
{
    public ChannelWhatsApp();

    [Column("WHATSAPP_UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Column("WHATSAPP_Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Column("WHATSAPP_DisplayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

url : http://172.19.22.81:5000/api/channelWhatsapp/saveDto

Channel Class :

```
public abstract class Channel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Channel();

    public virtual ICollection<Interaction> Interaction { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Schedule> Schedule { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Queue> Queue { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Session> Session { get; set; }
    public virtual ChannelBehavior ChannelBehavior { get; set; }
    public virtual EPS EPS { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DtLastChange { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string IntegrationServiceHost { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string RouterHost { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public int? IntegrationServiceRemotePort { get; set; }
    public int? RouterSocketPort { get; set; }
    public int? RouterRemotePort { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ChannelBehavior")]
    public int IDChannelBehavior { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EPS")]
    public int IDEPS { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int IDChannel { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string IconName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public byte? PendingPauseCode { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsPausePending { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public SystemUserOperator Operator { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime StateMomment { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public UserStateType CurrentState { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChannelSkill> ChannelSkills { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public ChannelTypeType Type { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
[Route("api/ChannelWhatsapp/{Action}")]
[ApiController]
public class ChannelWhatsappController : IrideController<ChannelWhatsApp>
{
    public ChannelWhatsappController(IrideContext context) : base(context) { }


    [HttpPost("")]
    [ActionName("saveDto")]
    public IActionResult saveDto([FromBody] ChannelWhatsApp entity)
    {
        try
        {

            ////Obtem o data 
            //entity.DtLastChange = IrideUtil.getDate() ;

            //_context.Set<ChannelWhatsApp>().Update(entity);
            //_context.SaveChanges();
            return Ok(entity);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Ok(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

returned error:

> Exception: Invalid channel IrideCM.Model.Channel..ctor()
>   IrideCM.Model.ChannelWhatsApp..ctor() lambda_method(Closure )
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateNewObject(JsonReader
>   reader, JsonObjectContract objectContract, JsonProperty
>   containerMember, JsonProperty containerProperty, string id, out bool
>   createdFromNonDefaultCreator) in JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs 
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member,
>   JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember,
>   object existingValue) in JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs 
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader
>   reader, Type objectType, bool checkAdditionalContent) in
>   JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you also parse your ChannelWhatsApp class ? It could be because your json payload and your ChannelWhatsApp class are somehow different.

Comment: @Skrface thanks, i added the classes in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting a payload to a controller in the request's body, you need to make sure the payload's structure matchs the structure of the expected class.

In your case, it does not match at all. You just need to post a payload with the same type as the type expected in the FromBody param of your endpoint.